# How can my GreaseMonkey script get the data which will be load by ajax later?

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script. And I found some elements was loaded by ajax. 
When my user script running, the data is not loaded.
  I try to use 'while' to wait for the ajax load the data, and it turn out to be the browser was locked and crash later.
  How can I wait the data loaded by ajax in an GreaseMonkey script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout( function  (  ) {
if ( data ){
    // if loaded
    // do something
} else {
    // wait a moment and check again
    setTimeout( arguments.callee , 500);
}
} , 500);
```